# time series or SVM for frecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, svm, forecasting

I am trying to apply machine learning algorithm to a dataset which consits of emission of pollutant gas from an engine called SO2(target variable) which is collected over 6 months of time for at a interval of each of 15 mins each.The dataset also do have other independent variables like pressure,vapour etc with time.
Now the question is
should i go for time series modelling like arima for forcasting the So2?
or should i go for randomforest or svm for forecasting?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not general advice on ML approaches & methodologies; your question is way too broad and primarily opinion-based, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you go for time-series modeling instead of SVM. Your SVM would consider i.i.d (independent and identically distributed) samples, and wouldn't consider the information that encapsulated across time.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you. It can consider information encapsulated across time with the help of good feature engineering.

Comment: @GIRISHkuniyal, I somewhat understand what you mean, but if the synthesized features are essentially generated with collating values across multiple time-points, you are essentially doing time-series modelling, no? I hope, my point is bit more clearer now. :)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Anant and Mr.Girish for providing valuable information